# Total list overview of vlocity_cmt__GeneralSettings__c values

Tags: customsetting, vlocity, omnistudio

For the use and correct configuration of the Vlocity CMT package I am looking for the total list of all the possible settings of the vlocity_cmt__GeneralSettings__c custom setting.

Are there more? Which? What are the possible values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a few, namely:

| Name | vlocity_cmt__Value__c | Purpose / Documentation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CalculationProcedureCachePartition | String | name of cache partition |
| ErrorLoggingEnabled | true/false |  |
| LoggingEnabled | true/false | https://docs.vlocity.com/en/Enable-Error-Logging.html |
| LoggingAddPrefix | no idea yet? |  |
| LoggingLevelDefault | ? | Default Logging Level |
| TimeTrackingEnabled | ? | ? |
| DefaultRequiredPermission | String | https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.os_dataraptor_and_integration_procedure_security_settings.htm&type=5&language=en_US |
| CheckCachedMetadataRecordSecurity | True or False | https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.os_dataraptor_and_integration_procedure_security_settings.htm&type=5&language=en_US |